# Javascript form being triggered by JQuery after changing id

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form that, once submitted, executes some JQuery using `$('#search_form').submit(function(){# execute code here});`. Later on in the code, I change the id of the form with `$('#search_form').attr('id', 'tags_form');`. Then, I have a different block of code when that form is triggered. The problem is that when I submit the form with the new id, it still triggers the old `.submit()`.

Comment: Changing a property or attribute of an element, or even it's contents, won't change what events are bound to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the `id` of an element doesn't remove existing handlers from it. Unbind it first:

```
$('#search_form').unbind('submit');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course because when you bound the event using new id `tags_form` at the start up it doesn't just exist. So event binding is of no effect there.

instead try using event delegation or bind the event after changing the id, or assign a classname for element and bind the event to the classname instead of the id.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#tags_form, #search_form', function(){# execute code here});
```

Or:

```
$('.myFormClass').submit(processForm); //where the classname on form is myFormClass
```

Or:

Say you event is like this:

```
$('#search_form').on('click', processForm); // or $('#search_form').click(processForm);
```

Later:

```
// some code...
$('#search_form').off('submit'); // unbind the handler  or  $('#search_form').unbind('click');
//In the Code block that changes the id
$('#tags_form').on('submit', processForm); // bind the handler to new element
```

Comment: Does this solution prevent the old function from firing as well?

Comment: Or you can unbind the old event like in the answer above.